# Create a vector of size x with two numbers randomly divided

Tags: python, arrays, random

I currently need to create an array of size x and fill it with either 1s or -1s randomly divided. I can easily create an array and fill it with randint but the problem with that would be that I do not want 0s in my array.

I also have a precise number of the length of the array so I need to make sure that I have in total 100 or 1000 ints in it.

If anyone knows how to solve this smoothly it would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `numpy.random.choice([-1, 1], 1000)`?

Comment: When filling the array just don't allow any `randint` values of `0`. Why would that be "unsmooth"?

Comment: I didn't know about the choice function, I'm still very new to numpy!

But thanks, this was very simple then

Answer (score 0):

As @roganjosh mentioned in the comments you could use [choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html), one alternative is to use [randint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) and shift the boundaries, like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = (2 * np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=10)) - 1
print(a)
```

**Output**

```
[ 1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1  1  1]
```

**Benchmarks**

```
import timeit

print(timeit.timeit('a = (2 * np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=1000)) - 1', setup='import numpy as np', number=10000))
print(timeit.timeit('a = np.random.choice([-1, 1], 1000)', setup='import numpy as np', number=10000))
```

**Output**

```
0.10986099799993099
0.18005346000063582
```